# How to use each ng-repeat item in a function

Tags: angularjs

I have a small program to add and remove rooms and increase and decrease number of Children in each room. Also I want to set the age of each child in the room.  I am facing an issue of how to bind ng-model names inside the ng-repeat. Please see following fiddle for my code

http://jsfiddle.net/ab23r/6/

```
$scope.incrementRoomCount = function(){
       count = count+1;
       $scope.roomList.push({roomCount:count});
   }
   $scope.addChildren = function(){
       childrenCount = childrenCount+1;
       this.noOfChildren = childrenCount;
       $scope.childAgeContainer = true;
   }
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to pass "room" to the functions and store the relevant data in that room. The variable `$index` is also available in the loop and can be useful.

```
<input name="" type="button" value="+" ng-click="addChildren(room)" />
<input name="child" type="text" style="text-align:center;" ng-model="room.count" />
<input name="" type="button" value="-" ng-click="removeChildren(room)" />
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$scope.roomList = [
  {count: 1}
];
$scope.addChildren = function(room){
  ++room.count;
};
$scope.removeChildren = function(room){
  --room.count;
 };
```

But, I didn't feel like going to sleep just yet, so here's a quick example of how I might approach your project: **[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/ePUtogOS/2/edit)**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <form>
    <button ng-click="addRoom()">Add Room</button>
    <div ng-repeat="room in rooms">
      <hr>
      <h2>Room {{$index+1}}</h2>
      <p>Child count: {{room.children.length}}</p>
      <button ng-click="room.tempChild={}">Add Child</button>
      <div ng-show="room.tempChild">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Child's Name" ng-model="room.tempChild.name">
        <input type="number" placeholder="Child's Age" ng-model="room.tempChild.age">
        <button ng-click="room.children.push(room.tempChild); room.tempChild=false">Submit</button>
        <button ng-click="room.tempChild=false">Cancel</button>
      </div>
      <h3>Children:</h3>
      <div ng-repeat="child in room.children">
        <span>Name: {{child.name}} Age: {{child.age}}</span><button ng-click="room.children.splice($index, 1)">x</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.rooms = [
    {
      children: [
        {name: 'Jack', age: 7}
      ]
    }
  ];
  $scope.addRoom = function() {
    $scope.rooms.push({children: []});
  };

});
```